# Java Swing in a Linux embedded system

Tags: java, linux, swing, user-interface, embedded

I need to run a Java Swing GUI application into a Linux Embedded system. Fortunately, it is an i386 system, however it needs to be minimal in terms of size used.
What are the minimal requirements of Java Swing?
Is it possible to run a java swing GUI without X11?
Do you recommend me another alternative for a Java GUI?

Answer (score 1):

Swing itself is built on awt, which in turn has adapters to GDI (on windows) or X (on unix). You could probably write that kind of adapter to interface with a framebuffer on your hardware, but i doubt very much you really want to do that.

So, yes, to run a swing GUI, you need X11 running.

Comment: It seems like (some implementation of) awt-on-directFB has already been done http://directfb.org/index.php/mailinglists/directfb-dev/2002/08-2002/msg00054.html

Comment: Since that message is 11 years old, and there's no mention of Java or AWT in the projects list, i doubt this is actively maintained .. but i'm crossing my fingers you find something that works.

Comment: It's in the repository, in theory it should built against whatever was contemporary http://git.directfb.org/?p=ports/kawt.git;a=summary